# SortInPlace not working as expected

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift2

I'm trying to make a program that implements a card game.  However, sorting a deck (array of cards) gives unexpected output.

My `Card.swift` file has the following comparison function, which first sorts by :

```
// For Comparable
public func <(left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {
    if left.suit < right.suit {
        return true
    }
    return left.rank < right.rank
}
```

Each `Card` has a `Rank` and a `Suit` (defined in `Rank.swift` and `Suit.swift`), which are `Int` enums with the following comparison operator:

```
public func <(left: Rank, right: Rank) -> Bool {
    return left.rawValue < right.rawValue
}
```

---

When I make a Euchre deck:

```
func makeEuchreDeck() {
    for suit in 1...4 {
        for rank in 9...14 {
            deck.append(Card.init(r: rank, s: suit))
        }
    }
}
```

and then sort it (via `deck.sortInPlace()`), it gives the following output (using the raw values for the Rank and Suit):

```
9 of 1
9 of 2
9 of 3
9 of 4
10 of 1 //inconsistency here
11 of 1 //something about Clubs makes it act up
12 of 1
10 of 2 //it acts normally except for Clubs from here on
10 of 3
10 of 4
11 of 2
11 of 3
11 of 4
12 of 2
12 of 3
12 of 4
13 of 1 //back to normal here
13 of 2 //yes, including Clubs
13 of 3
13 of 4
14 of 1
14 of 2
14 of 3
14 of 4
```

## Questions

1. Why is is acting so buggy with the 10, Jack, and Queen of Clubs (10, 11, and 12 of 1)?
2. It looks like the sorting function is acting oppositely of how I intended it.  I want it to sort by suit first, then by rank (like how you'd usually sort cards in your hand in a trick-taking game).  Expected output is all the Clubs, then all the Diamonds, etc....  Did I get something backwards in my sort function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparison function is not correct, it should be (for example)

```
public func <(left: Card, right: Card) -> Bool {

    // Compare `suit` first. If different, you are done.
    if left.suit != right.suit {
        return left.suit < right.suit
    }

    // Same `suit`, need to compare `rank`.
    return left.rank < right.rank
}
```

assuming that you want to sort by `suit` first and then by `rank`.

The error in your code is that it does not handle the case `left.rank > right.rank` correctly. It should return `false` in that case,
but it actually returns the result of  `left.rank < right.rank`.